# Add comma between all names in a list of object

Tags: c#

I am trying to do something quite simple, but for some reason, I can't do it effectively and looking good as I would expect it to be.

I have a collection of Persons and I need to separate the names with a comma for those who have the same email.

I tried to use `Aggregate` function but it returns one string for all emails. I can do it in a foreach loop but it seems to be not the best way.

Can someone advice me what a nice way would be to implement this?

This is the data:

```
var persons = new List<Person>
{
    new Person
    {
        Email = "A@gmail.com",
        Name = "Mori"
    },
    new Person
    {
        Email = "A@gmail.com",
        Name = "Tori"
    },
    new Person
    {
        Email = "A@gmail.com",
        Name = "Jake"
    },
    new Person
    {
        Email = "A@gmail.com",
        Name = "Jove"
    },
    new Person
    {
        Email = "B@gmail.com",
        Name = "John"
    },
    new Person
    {
        Email = "B@gmail.com",
        Name = "James"
    }
};
```

Expected Result:

Returns List:

1. Email (property): A@gmail.com  Name (property): Mori,Tori,Jake,Jove.
2. Email (property): B@gmail.com  Name (property): John,James.

Comment: It can be simple like this `persons.GroupBy(e => e.Email).Select(g => $"{g.Key}.
 Name: {string.Join(",",g.Select(e => e.Name)}")`

Comment: Sort the list based on emails. Then iterate through the list keeping track of the previous email. If the current email matches the previous email, append a comma to the list of names, then the current name. If not, you are done with the previous email.

Comment: @KingKing: why don't you post the same as answer?

Comment: @KingKing I think you didn't understand me correctly. You returned a string of all. I meant that there should be an List<Person> returned where the Email remains the same and the Name is aggregated with commas.

Comment: @un-lucky I think it's fairly simple, if any one has that same answer and would like to add it, just go ahead.

Comment: @MishaZaslavsky so you can ***project*** to new instances of Person easily using `Select`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building on King Kings answer:

```
var groupedByEmails = persons.GroupBy (p => p.Email)
                             .Select (p => new Person {
                                Email = p.Key,
                                Name = String.Join(", ", p.Select (x => x.Name))
                             }).ToList();
groupedByEmails.Dump(); //only in LinqPad
```

Although I wouldn't recommend using the Person class for this. I'd rather create a seperate viewmodel for that projection. That is because the person class describes a single person in that context. Using it to store some sort of person collection is a recipe for problems down the road.

Output:

[image]

At some point you will wonder if that `Person` now stores one name or multiples names and you will introduce some sort of if check `if(p.Name.indexOf(", ") != -1)` to deal with it and you keep piling up that debt. Just create a EmailPersonCollectionVm.cs

```
public class EmailPersonCollectionVm 
{
    public string Email { get; set;}
    public List<string> Names {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var res=from data in persons 
                group data by data.Email into groupdata
                select new
        {
            Email=groupdata.Key,
            Name=string.Join(",",groupdata.Select((x=>x.Name)).ToList())
        };
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
 var result = persons.GroupBy(c => c.Email).Select(c => new Person()
            {
                Email = c.First().Email,
                Name = string.Join(", ", c.Select(b=>b.Name).ToList())
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello Misha Zaslavsky,

in this cases you can easily use LINQ to Query and Format your output:

```
var maillist = from p in persons
               group p by p.Email into grp
               select new { grp.Key, Names=grp.Select(g => g.Name).ToArray() };

foreach( var entry in maillist) {
    Console.WriteLine($"EMail: {entry.Key} Names: {string.Join<string>(",", entry.Names)}" );
}
```