# linq to convert list based on Group

Tags: c#

Basically i have a employee collection which is containing the Below details. The below list is either available in DataTable Or List.

```
EmpId DeptId  Status
3     15      Registered
3     15      Completed
3     15      Discontinued
```

I want to convert this into a single record like this with Status as a comma separated values

```
EmplId DeptId Status
3      15     Registered, Completed, Discontinued
```

I want to know how it can be achieved either from DataTable or List. Please let me know for any suggestions

Comment: What is the difficulty that you are facing in LINQ query generation?

Comment: You can refer to this as your question is much alike: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47131148/add-comma-between-all-names-in-a-list-of-object/47131300#47131300

Comment: i need the code to do it

Comment: GroupBy? Like `employees.GroupBy(x => new { x.EmplId, x.DeptId }).Select(x => new EmployeeGroup{ EmplId = x.Key.EmplId, DeptId = x.Key.DeptId, Statis = string.Join(", ", x.Select(s => s.Status) }))`

Comment: If you start depends on SO for code writing service, you will become a copy paste machine, first make a try and come back

Comment: You don't get anybody to write the entire code for you. You have to at least have some idea or attempt already. In this case, you could probably do it quite simply, using a loop. It may not be the fastest way to do it (performance wise), but it should be somewhat simple.

Comment: I have given it in a simpler format for understanding and getting the result. Becuase the EmpID would not be in sorted order and the records are not consective

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try This Code

```
var res=(from item in Emp
             group item by new { item.EmpId,item.DeptId}  into groupData
             select new 
             {
                 EmpId=groupData.Key.EmplId,
                 DeptId=groupData.Key.DeptId,
                 Status=string.Join(",",groupData.Select((x=>x.Status)).ToList())
             }).ToList();
```